# (Pymongo) Python script insert data in MongoDB, counting how many data are modified

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm counting how many data are modified (counting how many were inserted this time)
I read through that https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/pymongo/results.html

usually`.inserted_count` and `.upserted_count` could do so
but somewhere would not correct

- The code

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json

def init_db(ip, db, coll):
    try:
        myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://' + ip + '/')
        mydb = myclient[db]
        mycol = mydb[coll]
        success_condition = "success on initializ operation"

    except Exception as e: 
        success_condition = "failed on initializ operation"
        
    return mydb, mycol, success_condition

  # ins_data = insert_db_data
def ins_data(one_or_many_bool, insert_values_json):
    try:    
        if one_or_many_bool == True:
            x = mycol.insert_many(insert_values_json)
        else:
            x = mycol.insert_one(insert_values_json)

        success_condition_insert = "success on ins_data operation"

    except Exception as e: 
        success_condition_insert = "failed on ins_data operation"

    return x , success_condition_insert

ip_input = input("Enter the ip: ")
exist_DB_name = input("Enter exist DB name: ")
exist_coll_name = input("Enter exist collection name: ")
mydb, mycol, success_condition  = init_db(ip_input, exist_DB_name, exist_coll_name)
print(success_condition)

insert_one_or_many = input("U are update one or many values? ( 1 for many, 0 for one ): ")
newvalues_str = input("Enter new values: ")

one_or_many_bool = bool(int(insert_one_or_many))
insert_values_json =json.loads(newvalues_str)

x , success_condition_insert = ins_data(one_or_many_bool, insert_values_json)
print(success_condition_insert)
print(x)
print(x.inserted_count, "documents insert.")
```

- and the output for `.inserted_count` and `.upserted_count`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.17_connect_mongoD_練習\3333@@@@.py",line 57, in 
> print(x.upserted_count, "documents insert.")
> AttributeError: 'InsertManyResult' object has no attribute 'upserted_count'

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.17_connect_mongoD_練習\3333@@@@.py",line 57, in 
> print(x.upserted_count, "documents insert.")
> AttributeError: 'InsertManyResult' object has no attribute 'inserted_count'

the output of `print(x)` and `print(type(x))`

> <pymongo.results.InsertManyResult object at 0x0000018804A0A560>
> <class 'pymongo.results.InsertManyResult'>

I just tried that same concept for `update` the `.modified_count`is working
**- code of update method**
[image: (Pic) code of update method]

**- output of update method**
[image: (Pic) output of update method]

Comment: What is `type(x)`?

Comment: that a good point @rickhg12hs, I just update print(x) , and print(type(x)) result

Comment: So your question is resolved?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, I still stock on can not count and print new `insert value` , I just said for same idea in `update` is working. There have four opreation for Database, "Update" , "Delete" ,  "Insert", "Query", and I do want to extract the result and count how many data are effect, that where I stock

Comment: All of the properties may be found in the docs.  https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html